# Pandas change value of a column based another column condition

Tags: data-mining, pandas

I have values in column1, I have columns in column2.
What I want to achieve: Condition: where column2 == 2 leave to be 2 if
 column1 < 30 elsif change to 3 if column1 > 90.

Here is what i did so far, the problem is 2 does not change to 3 where column1 > 90.

```
filter1 = data['column1']
for x in filter1:
    if x < 30:
        data['column2'] = data['column2'].replace([2], [2])
    else:
        data['column2'] = data['Output'].replace([2], [3])
```

Comment: Thanks peter for the edit!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What I want to achieve: Condition: where column2 == 2 leave to be 2 if column1 < 30 elsif change to 3 if column1 > 90

This can be simplified into `where (column2 == 2 and column1 > 90) set column2 to 3`. The `column1 < 30` part is redundant, since the value of `column2` is only going to change from 2 to 3 if `column1 > 90`.

In the code that you provide, you are using pandas function [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html), which operates on the *entire* Series, as stated in the reference:

> Values of the Series are replaced with other values dynamically. This differs from updating with .loc or .iloc, which require you to specify a location to update with some value.

This means that for each iteration of `for x in filter1` your code performs global replacement, which is not what you want to do - you want to update the specific row of `column2` that corresponds to `x` from `column1` (which you are iterating over).

> the problem is 2 does not change to 3 where column1 > 90

This is truly strange. I would expect the code you provided to have changed every instance of 2 in `column2` to 3 as soon as it encountered an `x >= 30`, as dictated by your code conditional statement (the execution of the `else` branch). This discrepancy may stem from the fact that you are assigning to `column2` the result of global replacement performed on the column `Output` (the contents of which are unknown). In any case, if you want your program to do something under a specific condition, such as `x > 90`, it should be explicitly stated in the code. You should also note that the statement `data['column2'] = data['column2'].replace([2], [2])` achieves nothing, since 2 is being replaced with 2 and the same column is both the source and the destination.

What you could use to solve this particular task is a boolean mask (or the [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method). Both are explained in an excellent manner in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315452/selecting-with-complex-criteria-from-pandas-dataframe).

Using a boolean mask would be the easiest approach in your case:

```
mask = (data['column2'] == 2) & (data['column1'] > 90)
data['column2'][mask] = 3
```

The first line builds a Series of booleans (True/False) that indicate whether the supplied condition is satisfied.
The second line assigns the value 3 to those rows of `column2` where the mask is True.

Comment: Hi Vlad_Z, i really do appreciate your time and the insights. Thank you. However, the problem still persist. There are other values in column2 that shouldn't change, the changes should only be at places where column2 == 2.

Comment: Sad to hear that the problem persists. Could you perhaps post the modified code that didn't work for you? and a couple of rows of data in question to demonstrate the issue? I'm really intrigued as to why this didn't work on your end, since the boolean mask approach is quite a standard way of performing selective updates in pandas.

Comment: Oh mine! Having seen your post i checked again and it really worked as well.

Comment: Thank you! I'm really glad that you got your own solution going as well.

Comment: @Vlad_Z I get `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`, what I guess happens is that the mask is applied to a copy. However it seems to work.

Answer (score 10):

I've had success approaching this in a slightly different way.

```
import numpy as np

data['column2'] = np.where((data['column1'] < 30)
                           & (data['column2'] ==2), #Identifies the case to apply to
                           data['column2'],      #This is the value that is inserted
                           data['column2'])      #This is the column that is affected
data['column2'] = np.where((data['column1'] > 90)
                           & (data['column2'] ==2), #For rows with column1 > 90
                           data['column3'],      #We place column3 values
                           data['column2'])      #In column two
```

This is a little wordier than a loop, but I've found it to be the most intuitive way to do this sort of data manipulation with pandas.

Comment: Thank you Abram, the code is not quite there yet because there are other values in column2 that shouldn't change, the changes should only be at places where column2 == 2.

Comment: I modified the code a little, this should leave those other values alone and only change column2 where it is equal to 2.

Comment: Thank you so much, Abram. It sure worked as desired.

Answer (score 8):

While i was waiting for answer, i got something working too

```
def myfunc(x,y):
    if x <= 30 and y == 2:
        return y
    elif x > 90 and y == 2:
        return y + 1
    else:
        return y

data['column2'] = data.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x.column1, x.column2), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> This can be simplified into where (column2 == 2 and column1 > 90) set
> column2 to 3. The column1 < 30 part is redundant, since the value of
> column2 is only going to change from 2 to 3 if column1 > 90.

Agreed with @Vlad_Z. This can now be done in one line using [dataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
data.loc[(data['column1'] > 90) & (data['column2'] == 2), 'column2'] = 3
```